# Mapbox / Leaflet invalidateSize "undefined"

Tags: jquery, undefined, leaflet, mapbox

I'm getting an "undefined" error on map.invalidateSize(); when I switch between tabs on the page as suggested here:
https://www.mapbox.com/help/blank-tiles/

Test Page:
http://edmo2016.wpengine.com/locations/palo-alto/#locationTabs1

Here is the code:

```
jQuery('#locationTabs').easyResponsiveTabs({
    tabidentify: 'main-tabs',
    activate: function() {
        if ( typeof map !== 'undefined' ) {
            map.invalidateSize(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your

```
jQuery('#locationTabs').easyResponsiveTabs({
    tabidentify: 'main-tabs',
    activate: function() {
        if ( typeof map !== 'undefined' ) {
            map.invalidateSize(false);
        }
    }
});
```

inside the `window.load` callback, because right now the `map` you are trying to reach is out of scope.Place it on a new line after the `addTo`.